# Strange directory name, shown with a backslash

Tags: directory, filenames

I have copied and pasted a directory of files into another.

The result is now this one  `development\ /`

I do not know what that means? Linux does not even recognize it as a directory now.

Also the owner of this directory is wrong. But when I try to do this  `chown -R zugul /development`, the result is: `` chown: cannot access `/development': No such file or directory ``

Looks like something went wrong when I have pasted the copied directory. How can I fix this issue?

Comment: i think the \ is escaping a space. try enclosing the path in double quotes and adding a space

Answer (score 1):

Your directory name seems to have a space in it.

You can either use quotes:

```
chown -R zugul "/development /"
```

Or you can use escape characters:

```
chown -R zugul /development\ /
```

Comment: ok but how do I fix the space issue? I cannot even see it the folder live. It fires a 404 error..

Comment: `mv "/development " "/development"`. Or you can add `%20` to your URL: `foo.com/development%20`

Answer (score 1):

Your directory name ends with a space (probably a regular space, but it could be some other blank character like an unbreakable space). Depending on what options you passed to `ls`, the `\` either is in the file name or indicates that the next character is to be interpreted literally as part of the file name.

You'll want to rename the directory:

```
mv /development\  /development
```

(note the two consecutive spaces: the first is part of the file name and quoted by the preceding backslash, and the second space separates the two arguments). Or

```
mv '/development ' /development
```

If there is already a directory called `/development`, move the files from the `/development ​` directory to `/development` then remove the badly-named directory (`rmdir '/development '`). Watch out for conflicts (files existing in both).

Once you've settled the naming issue, take care of other things such as ownership.

Answer (score 0):

The filename is incorrect when you try to `chown`; try instead `chown -R zugul development\\\ /`.

Answer (score 0):

Don't think this belongs to stackoverflow but basically you can do one of 2 things:

```
chown -R zugul /development*
```

If you have multiple /development directories it's a problem.  Or

```
chown -R zugul "/development /"
```

In general though you might want to avoid making "development" directories part of the / level.  These usually belong to `/home/zugul/` somewhere.

Unless you copied the folder as root you won't see it in `/`.  So either your operation failed or the folder in some other directory.  If it is in some other directory then you need to do:

```
cd <dest directory>
sudo chown -R zugul "development /"
```

Comment: ok but how do I fix the space issue? I cannot even see it the folder live. It fires a 404 error..

Comment: See the edit to the answer.  I think you have confused things a little bit.  It seems you are mixing the UNIX/Linux shell with Web Access.  So you might want to clarify the issue before continuing.

Answer (score 0):

Instead of guessing what the character is, use something that quotes the special chars.  I like this method:

`ls --quoting-style=shell-escape`

That shows what it actually is (using bash/ksh-style `$''` strings which handle ANSII C escapes).  As a bonus, that should give you a pre-quoted string that you can directly pass to `chown` or whatever else you need to do in the shell.  For example, here's a file with a newline in the name, showing the ls output and then using the pre-quoted `ls` output for `chgrp` and `rm`:

```
sauer@lightning:/tmp/test> ls -l
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 sauer users 0 Aug 14 17:04 a?file
sauer@lightning:/tmp/test> ls -l --quoting-style=shell-escape
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 sauer users 0 Aug 14 17:04 'a'$'\n''file'
sauer@lightning:/tmp/test> chgrp docker 'a'$'\n''file'
sauer@lightning:/tmp/test> ls -l --quoting-style=shell-escape
total 0
-rw-r--r-- 1 sauer docker 0 Aug 14 17:04 'a'$'\n''file'
sauer@lightning:/tmp/test> rm -v 'a'$'\n''file'
removed 'a'$'\n''file'
```

I'd suggest renaming the file to something without weird chars. :)

```
sauer@lightning:/tmp/test> ls
a??file
sauer@lightning:/tmp/test> ls --quoting-style=shell-escape
'a'$'\t\033''file'
sauer@lightning:/tmp/test> mv -v 'a'$'\t\033''file' regular_filename
renamed 'a'$'\t\033''file' -> 'regular_filename'
```